# Read SELinux in Android device

Tags: android, android-source, selinux

I added few SELinux pemission in `android/system/sepolicy`. After build Image, I want to check that the permission is added in build. How can I check the added SELinux after flashing the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the policy file and analyze it.

```
adb pull /sys/fs/selinux/policy
```

But if you added it to `system/sepolicy` and built/flashed the images, I don't see how they could not have been applied.

If you're still seeing denials even after adding the allow rules, it's either
a) There is another denial that appeared after the last allow
b) There is also MSL security at hand. See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45551191/3801327

Comment: /sys/fs/selinux/policy is a binary file, what tools can I use to analyze it?